# Java Object Array IO

Tags: java, arrays, file, object, io

I have an Array of Objects called "person" and i need to save that data, Is there a way to output an array and then input it back into the program.  I have tried simply outputting the raw String and int data that makes up each "person" and the program never writes that data to the specified txt file.  Is there a method or function that can write raw object data and then retrieve it?

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look to ObjectOutputStream and ObjectOutputStream and the Serializable interface. What you are trying to do is to serialize your data to a file and load (deserialize) it back again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use standard Java serialisation. Another trivial solution is to use [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org), which will serialise your objects into/from XML. You don't need to implement specific interfaces or annotate your objects (by default) and you'll get a readable (in XML terms) serialisation, which can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You need serialization. Read [this](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/).

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use Serialization provided by Java. You need to implement the `java.io.Serializable` interface and write and read to and from the **ObjectOutputStream** and **ObjectInputStream** classes to store and retrieve data respectively.